# How to preserve text formatting in Powershell variable output?

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I am using the code below on my PS script to catch part of Robocopy output and send it via email but it does not maintain the output format.

```
$roboresult = (Get-Content $tmpdest\$RoboLog | Select-Object -first 15)
$roboresult += (Get-Content $tmpdest\$RoboLog | Select-Object -last 10)
$roboresult
```

It comes out on the email like the following (Not formatted);

> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------    Started : Tue Apr 09 09:27:17 2019     Source : I:~temp\SIGNO\
> Dest : \BRC\H$~temp\SIGNO\      Files : *.*            Options : *.* /X
> /NDL /NFL /S /E /COPY:DAT /MOVE /Z /NP /MT:8 /R:10 /W:5
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------                 Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras     Dirs :
> 1235      1235         0         0         0         0    Files :
> 147408    147408         0         0         0         0    Bytes :
> 79.215 g  79.215 g         0         0         0         0    Times :  27:56:05   2:47:50                       0:00:00   0:21:21     Ended :
> Tue Apr 09 12:36:29 2019

How can I make so I receive in the email formatted?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible with how you construct your mail message command. If I set up the same situation you have here, I will end up with an `$roboresult` variable with 25 lines of formatted code. You will need to convert that to a string to use `send-mailmessage` if you are sending it as the body of the email. If you join each line with **CRLF** characters, you should preserve the formatting in email.

```
send-mailmessage -from recipient@domain.com -to you@domain.com -subject "Robocopy Results" -body ($roboresult -join "`r`n") -smtpserver servername
```

Based on your comments, you should be able to replace `$roboresult` with the following:

```
$($roboresult -join "`r`n")
```

Comment: I have it constructed like this.... 

`code`
$subject = "ROBOCOPY terminado en $(Get-Content env:computername) / $AccToMove"
$body = "ROBOCOPY se ha finalizado la copia en el servidor $(Get-Content env:computername). `n`nORIGEN: $tmpsource\$AccToMove `nDESTINO: $tmpdest\$AccToMove.  `n`n$roboresult `n`nConectese al servidor para autorizar que continue..."
Send-MailMessage -To $to -CC $cc -From $from -SMTPServer $smtp -Subject $subject -Body $body -Attachments $tmpdest\$RoboLog
`code`

don't know where to put the "-join "`r`n""

Thanks @AdminOfThings

Comment: @Heyvoon, I added a comment to my answer that may help you with the formatting. You just need to replace `$roboresult`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old, but just to share. Try the below snippet.

```
roboresult += (Get-Content $tmpdest\$RoboLog -Tail 15)

$roboresult = $roboresult -join "`r`n"
Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml "<pre><code>$roboresult</code></pre>" ...
```